# Weka: Why does the re-evaluation with my test set doesn't give any results without throwing an error message?

Tags: testing, machine-learning, classification, weka, named-entity-recognition

I'm writing my master thesis about named entity recognition with German texts and I wanted to use Weka for the machine learning part. I am new to Weka so I don't understand why I don't get a result although the training process was successful and I got a model.

I trained a model with J48, the other with NaiveBayes. First, I got the error messages that have already been discussed on stackoverflow (train and test set were not compatible) but I corrected this. So, when I re-evaluate I do not get any error message and Weka gives out results, but these results don't contain anything else than zeros:

=== Re-evaluation on test set ===

User supplied test set
Relation:     train-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal-R1-10,12-last
Instances:     unknown (yet). Reading incrementally
Attributes:   15

=== Summary ===

Total Number of Instances                0
Ignored Class Unknown Instances             207484

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

```
           TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        O
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        I-PER
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        I-LOC
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        I-MISC
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        I-ORG
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        B-MISC
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        B-LOC
             0         0          0         0         0          ?        B-ORG
```

Weighted Avg.  NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN

=== Confusion Matrix ===

a b c d e f g h   <-- classified as

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | a = O

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | b = I-PER

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | c = I-LOC

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | d = I-MISC

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | e = I-ORG

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | f = B-MISC

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | g = B-LOC

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | h = B-ORG

My test and training data contain only nominal and numeric data, the header of the arff files are identical and I don't get any error message from Weka. Therefore, I have no idea where I did something wrong and what I have to do to get a result. I tried it with Weka version 3-6 and version 3-7-10 but the results where always the same.

Does anyone have an idea why the evaluation of my test set does not work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that maybe WEKA doesn't know which is the class attribute in your data? In the Weka Explorer GUI under the "Classify" tab, there is an drop-down list to select the class attribute - make sure the correct class is selected.

If this is not the issue, have you made sure that your test data is valid and can be processed in WEKA? A simple test would be to train a model using your original test data (e.g. as the temporary training data) using WEKA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your suggestion seemed to be right. I now indicated the class to evaluate and I got a result. The remaining problem is now that the re-evaluation does not take all the instances provided in the development set, but only evaluates the first 4000 instances instead of about 50 000 instances.